# Delivery reporting for RabbitMQ STOMP producer?

Tags: rabbitmq, mq, stomp

I am trying to find out if it is possible for a STOMP producer to receive "delivered to Consumer" delivery reports for messages sent to queues?

I know the producer can receive receipts from the broker by indicating persistence:true in the SEND frame as shown on rabbitmq website:

"Receipts for SEND frames with persistent:true are not sent until a confirm is received from the broker." - https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html

At the consumer end it is possible to indicate to the broker that a message is successfully delivered to the consumer only on receipt of an ACK by adding "ack: 'client'" to the SEND frame.

However, I've not found a method for end to end delivery receipts or perhaps I've misunderstood the references?  Grateful for any pointers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a member of the RabbitMQ, end to end acknowledgement is not available.  I'll need to create my own line of communication for such acknowledgements.